# Linear Algebra, how to solve transformation T: ℙ2→M 2,2?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Could someone please help me with two questions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/821VK.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiQvB.jpg)

So I know they must be a basis of P3, so

```
p = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3
```

I then need to find a way to sub the equation inside but I have no idea how to do so. 
I am using the Lyryx textbook, which did not really explain any of the steps so if anyone could teach me step by step, that would be great help!

Thank you!

Comment: Remember a special property of linear transformations, namely that $L(a\overrightarrow{x} + b\overrightarrow{y}) = aL(\overrightarrow{x}) + bL(\overrightarrow{x})$. If you can get a linear combination of polynomials to equal another polynomial, use the corresponding combination of the matrices to get the transformation.

Comment: elcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

First one:  $2q-p=r\implies T(r)=T(2p-q)=2T(p)-T(q)=\begin{pmatrix}5&11\\-21&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Second:  You get a system of $4$ equations in $4$ unknowns.  $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_3(x+1)+a_4(x^3+x^2+x+2)$.

Multiply through and set the coefficients equal.   Solve the system.

I get:  $a_1=a+c-d\\a_2=b+c-d\\a_3=2c-d \\a_4=-c+d$.

Now use the matrices given and the linear property.   I get

> $\begin{pmatrix}9a+3b-3d&-6a+3b\\-5a-b+2c-6d&4a-b-3c+5d\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Hello, what is the process you took to get to that?

Comment: Honestly I just looked at it to get $r=2q-p$.  In general,  you get a system of equations.